# Difference between .Value and .Text of a DateTimePicker - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I'd created a small piese of software which is used to calculate some information based on the users' birthdates. One of them is the number of days alive. Basically, i used `DateDiff` function in VB.NET to achieve this but there was one problem and i haven't figgured it out yet.

I use the .Value to assign the value of the DateTimePicker to a variable and use DateDiff with it as followed:

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtDOB, Today)
```

The problem is when i chose a date before the current date (yesterday), the result given was 0 when it should be 1 instead.

When i changed the `.Value` to `.Text` and store the value to the same variable. The result given was 1. This is what i expected but i don't know what's wrong with .Value property.
When i did my research, most websites i visited suggested to use `.Value` to transfer value from a DateTimePicker to a variable but somehow it seems to be not accurate.

Can someone tell me the difference between them two?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A `DatePicker.Value` returns a `Date` object, where as `DatePicker.Text` returns a `String` representation of that date.

After examining the values returned by `Today` and the output from `DatePicker.Value`, I've arrived at that `.Value` returns a `Date` object with a time (by default, the current time) along the date, where as `Today` only returns the current date. When plugged into `DateDiff()`, the method will assume the time on `Today` is 12:00AM, and by comparing the times, it may come to less than a day (which interpreted by VB as a full 24 hours between both dates), leading to 0 days. If you are not planning on counting the hours and minutes, use `DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtDOB.Date, Today)`.